# How to increment a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following string:

```
aRandomString
```

I'm then checking my database to see if that string has been used before (or if there's any string that starts with the given one). If it has, I'd like to increment it. The result would be the following:

```
aRandomString1
```

If that string exists, it would become `aRandomString2`, and so on. I'm assuming I need to complete the following steps: 1. Check for trailing numbers or set to 0, 2. Increment those trailing numbers by 1, append that number to the original string. Just trying to figure out a solid way to accomplish this!

**Update**

This is what I have so far:

```
var incrementString = function( str ){
    var regexp = /\d+$/g;
    if( str.match(regexp) )
    {
        var trailingNumbers = str.match( regexp )[0];
        var number = parseInt(trailingNumbers);
        number += 1;

        // Replace the trailing numbers and put back incremented
        str = str.replace(/\d+$/g , '');
        str += number;
    }else{
        str += "1";
    }
    return str;
}
```

I feel like this should be easier though.

Comment: Do you have an attempt at the algorithm you outlined?

Comment: The only numbers in your string will be at the end of it?

Comment: @Felipe, no, there could be numbers elsewhere.

Comment: @ajp15243 not yet. Will post an attempt momentarily.

Comment: @NickONeill If there can be numbers in other parts of the string, then you should probably choose a character unique from any other characters that the string can contain, and use that to separate your string from the incremental number at the end. That way you won't confuse it if you have a string that, without the incrementing number, is of the form `x123` (where `123` can be confused with the incrementing number that you'll stick on the end).

Comment: @ajp15243 I've posted the algorithm so far.

Comment: @NickONeill Given Felipe's question, your answer to it, and my comment based on that, what if you have the string `1Test2String3`, where `3` is not the increment number (so this string is non-incremented right now)? Is this a valid string for you to deal with?

Comment: @ajp15243 yep. Although that's a good point. I should be removing all trailing numbers from the initial string to avoid conflicts in the search.

Comment: @ajp15243 Actually, I'm not sure it matters. If the number is there, `1Test2String3` will become `1Test2String4` and that's fine.

Comment: In that case, your solution is probably fine. I don't think there is a simpler way than the `/\d+$/` regex, unless you separate your increment number with a unique character (e.g. `;`). With that, you could just do `str.split(';')` (returns an array of the pieces) and refer to the `0`th index for your raw string, and the `1`st index for your increment number, and then use `arr.join(';')` to recreate your incremented string after incrementing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function incrementString(str) {
  // Find the trailing number or it will match the empty string
  var count = str.match(/\d*$/);

  // Take the substring up until where the integer was matched
  // Concatenate it to the matched count incremented by 1
  return str.substr(0, count.index) + (++count[0]);
};
```

If the match is the empty string, incrementing it will first cast the empty string to an integer, resulting the value of 0. Next it preforms the increment, resulting the value of 1.

Comment: Wow, this was incredibly elegant!

Comment: But in the case of input string with zero prefix e.g. 001 not working properly...

Comment: updated @adamduren 's answer to handle leading zeros, below is for number with 3 digits, e.g. 001 


    return str.substr(0, count.index) + ("000" + (++count[0])).slice(-3);

Answer (score 5):

I had to keep the leading zeros in the number, this is how I did it:

```
function incrementString (string) {  
  // Extract string's number
  var number = string.match(/\d+/) === null ? 0 : string.match(/\d+/)[0];
  
  // Store number's length
  var numberLength = number.length

  // Increment number by 1
  number = (parseInt(number) + 1).toString();
  
  // If there were leading 0s, add them again
  while (number.length < numberLength) {
    number = "0" + number;
  }
    
  return string.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').concat(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing string with support for padding zeros `A001` will become `A002`. And support for plain string `ABC` will become `ABC1`.
And adding digits when needed: `ABC9` will become `ABC10`. I've used simular function for invoice number incremention.

````
  const incrementNr = (nr) => {
    const [nrDigits] = /\d*$/.exec(nr);
    const next = '' + (+nrDigits + 1);
    const nextNr = nr.slice(0, nr.length - Math.min(next.length, nrDigits.length)) + next;
    return nextNr;
  };```
````